# Visual Studio Hybrid App Debugger Unable to attach. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: android, debugging, cordova, visual-studio-2013, ibeacon

Ever since I have been developing a hybrid app using Cordova in Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7 I have not been able to get the debugger to attach because the system cannot find the file specified.

There is a message in the Debug output box that mentions web socket.  I have completed the webSocket4Net.dll part of the install and my Visual Studio is installed on a system drive.

Anyone know why I might be getting this error?  Developing without a debugger is getting pretty annoying so any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This may happen when Visual Studio is installed on a non-system drive. If that's the case, you can work around it by copying the assembly typescriptSourceMapReader.dll from

\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
to the same location on the drive where Visual Studio is installed.
Relaunching VS after doing this should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue just now. Running the file "vs2013mda_0.3.exe" (Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova CTP3.0) and selecting the "Repair" option fixed the "Unable to attach" issue for me.